# PLC SCL keeping variable true

Tags: plc

So I am writing a PLC code in SCL language and I am wondering about this thing:

I have a tank with an inlet and a pump for flow out. The pump should only run after the level in the tank goes beyond a level, lets say 10 meters. And it should keep going until the tank level goes down to 4 meters.

Not sure if I should use more IF statements or maybe a WHILE statement?. Problem is, how to keep the pump going **after** the level has gone under 10 meters but not yet reached 4 meters?

This code would probably not be useful:

```
IF (TankLevel > 10) THEN
      StartPump := TRUE;
END_IF;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `elsif`

```
IF (TankLevel > 10) THEN
    StartPump := TRUE;
ELSIF (TankLevel < 4) THEN
    StartPump := FALSE;
END_IF;
```

A PLC program is basically one big `while` loop, so this can be checked every few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following:

```
IF (TankLevel < 4) THEN
      StartPump := FALSE;
END_IF;
```

Comment: Yeah its silly I was thinking way to advanced. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another option, although this is more suited to ladder logic:

```
StartPump := ( (TankLevel > 10) OR StartPump ) AND NOT (TankLevel < 4);
```

The StartPump bit will be "latched" at 10m until it is released at 4m.

Comment: I never learned ladder but nice to know, thanks!